# Can my Parents refuse to let me go to my husbands house to live once married?

Tags: nikah, parents, husband-wife

I am to be married and my to-be-husband wants me to go and live with him in his home where his whole family is. He has a job there also. The problem is my parents do not want to send me as it is in another state and I might not get a good enough job according to what I have studied (as it is a rural area so to speak as I live in the capital city). And as I'm the only daughter they are a little more protective. I have no objection in going. Will it be wrong for me to go even if my parents don't like it?

Comment: How old are you? I would always advise with listening to your parents since they know more about life. Also you shouldn't move in until you are actually married to avoid fitnah.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally expected for a wife to live in her husband's home:

> ... a woman is the guardian of her husband's home ... -- [Sahih al-Bukhari 7138](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/93/2)

In clashes between husband and parents, priority is given to the husband, as Sheikh Muhammad Saleh Al-Munajjid ([AboutIslam](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/family/what-comes-first-obeying-my-husband-or-my-parents/)) explains:

> But if there arises any conflict between this and that (i.e. upon receiving conflicting orders from both her parents and her husband, assuming that both orders are aiming at good) then priority should be given to the command of the husband.

This is also confirmed in other fatawa: Islam Q&A ([1](https://islamqa.info/en/43123); [2](https://islamqa.info/en/110845)); [IslamHelpline.net](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/7581).